# android studio error cant resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have tried out Android Studio but now i have a Problem in my code i have tried to find a button but this dont work
with this code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Menu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnspielen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnspielen);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        btnspielen.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {}
}
```

but the problem now is that Android Studio says cant resolve Symbol R 
and I don't know why and the day before it Worked.

Comment: and what is R? if it's not a class in the same package as that one, import it. or figure out what you do need there

Comment: Look at the code in the Video https://youtu.be/F-k5gwz_91o?t=984 in line 21

Comment: so basically, you are following a vague crappy tutorial and can't figure out why it won't work.. I would recommend finding some better resources to study from

Comment: ok thanks for help

Comment: @coolian Try to go to File --> Invalidate Cathes & Restart --> Invalidate & restart. If it doesn't help - maybe something is wrong with the xml.

Comment: i will trying it

Comment: That does not Work it says grdle build finished with one Errors null vulue entry: increment Folder = null